# Tables and paging

Tags: gwt, pagination, flextable

Would be grateful for any ideas.

***Requirement***

(A) a table containing

```
A.1 text columns
A.2 one column for HTML content
A.3 one column to house a radio button group
```

(B) the ability to page through the records, e.g. by use of SimplePager.

***Alternatives considered so far***

1. FlexTable - can provide all of (A) but not (B)
2. CellTable - can provide A.1 and (B), but not A.2 nor A.3

Can anyone suggest an alternative(s) that provides all of A and B? I have looked also at Smart GWT but don't see anything I can use. But I'm not very experienced in either GWT or Smart GWT.

Thank you.

---

[edit 1] Radio button group with three buttons now created as follows ('InterimReport' is my data type):

```
Column<InterimReport, SafeHtml> radioButtonColumn = new Column<InterimReport, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {

    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(InterimReport object) {
    String s = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"selection\"" + object.get("dbIndex") + " value=\"match\" /> match<br />"+ "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"selection\"" + object.get("dbIndex")+ " value=\"nomatch\" /> no match<br />" + "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"selection\""+ object.get("dbIndex") + " value=\"urlnotfound\" /> URL not found</>";

    return SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(s);
    }
};
```

[edit 2] But how to capture the user's selection of a radio button? This code fragment doesn't appear to do anything:

```
radioButtonColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<InterimReport, SafeHtml>() {
    public void update(int index, InterimReport object, SafeHtml value) {
        System.out.println("Reached here");
        if (value.equals("match")) {
            setMatch(object.get("dbIndex"), index);
        } else if (value.equals("nomatch")) {
            setNoMatch(object.get("dbIndex"), index);
        } else if (value.equals("urlnotfound")) {
            setUrlNotFound(object.get("dbIndex"), index);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you say CellTable can't provide A.2 and A.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CellTable can hold HTML content (`SafeHtmlCell`) and so can also hold a radio button group.  Just use `<input type="radio" name="whatever"/>` as the HTML.  You just can't use *Widgets* in a CellTable - everything else will still work.

```
Column<YourType, SafeHtml> radioColumn = new Column<YourType, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell())
{
    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(YourType object)
    {
        return generateInputHtmlFromObject(object);
    }
}

cellTable.addColumn(radioColumn);
```

(sorry, untested code.  Maybe I misremember a method signature, or something)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Riley. I have successfully created the radio button group (see edit 1 above) but cannot get the user's selection of a radio button to register - the println in edit 2 is not reached. Am I using setFieldUpdater() in the right manner?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to setFieldUpdater, but unfortunately the SafeHtmlCell implementation does not actually call its field updater! Frustrating, I know.  You can either set an id on your `<input>` tags and use the `DOM` package to get the value (will only work passively :() or you can subclass SafeHtmlCell to make it call its valueupdater when you click or select the input (is confusing).  Look at the source of `com.google.gwt.cell.client.CheckboxCell` to see how Google did it for checkboxes.  Good luck!  Once you get through the mind-numbing learning curve, the Cell stuff is quite nice.