# Paging in FlexTable with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I need to implement "paging" for my application's FlexTable widget:

Here is my initial code where it renders a Product into a 3 column cell:

```
public void renderProducts(Map<Long, Product> mp) { 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator(); 
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();

        Product product = (Product) pairs.getValue();
        ProductWidget pw = productInstance.get();
        pw.setTitle(product.getName());
        pw.setImageUrl(product.getImageUrl());
        pw.setContent(product.getInfo());
        pw.setUrl(product.getUrl()); // "More" button anchor
        List<String> feats = product.getFeatures();
        for (String f : feats){
            pw.addFeature(f);
        }

        flextable.setWidget(i, j, pw);
        j++;
        if (j == 3){ 
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Need to do paging in N pages for this. My initial idea is to split the Map into a List of Map...

I mean, is there any "data source" for FlexTable?

Comment: You have a model and need paging, so why not CellTable/DataGrid? Just asking.

Comment: I need to insert a widget into the "cell" of the flextable, see: flextable.setWidget(...)

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use the FlexTable and provide paging you had better do it using a cell table [so older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583861/tables-and-paging). The simple pager implements all the functionality you want either way.

If you want to go with the FlexTable you have to provide with your own implementation of a pager. This can be done in varous ways, with next and previous button or Labels adding the on click handler and doing the iterations.

The map is also not the way to go as the items are not ordered in any way. I would add all the items to a List and use said list as my data source.

You also need a way to save the current page and the items/page ( maybe a static variable if you want it saved even after the page has changed )

Comment: Yah but I don't find Cell Table to be easily hold a Widget. What I am trying to display is a Product widget not really a text

Comment: That is not a problem, though the solution is a bit complicated, but rather straightforward once you grasp the basic concept. Use custom cells. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells